# how to change string to a a longer string?

Tags: ida

I am really new to IDA pro.

I tried changing hex but it messed up the whole thing

I want to change a string "Hd-Player" to "pickheadless"

its possible to change it using hex but it must be the same length with the original string i change but if its longer, it messed up the whole thing

How do i chang that string to  a bit longer string?

I tried using HxD and searched the "Hd-player" hex and changed it but it wont work at all.